# Перенаправить со страницы корзины на страницу магазина, если в корзине нет товаров

Tags: wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

Я использую плагин Woocommerce и CMS WordPress. Мне нужно чтобы когда из корзины пользователь удалил товар - страница перезагрузилась. У меня в functions.php есть код который перенаправляет пользователя на страницу магазина (shop) если в корзине нет товаров, но он работает только если страница перезагрузилась или пользователь кликнул на иконку корзины когда она пустая. Вот этот код -- >

```
function cart_empty_redirect_to_shop() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_page('cart') and !sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_shop' );
```

В идеале хорошо бы было если после ajax запроса было сделано перенаправление, если корзина пустая, а не после перезагрузки. Зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у wc есть js ивенты которые тригерятся после определенных событий, в вашем случае нужен ивент которые тригерится после того как из корзины удален последний товар `wc_cart_emptied` используя этот ивент вы можете перенаправить пользователя на страницу магазина js

```
jQuery( function($){
    jQuery( document.body ).on( 'wc_cart_emptied', function(){
        console.log('test');
        // window.location = '/shop';
    } );
} );
```

так же я бы заменил вашу версию редиректа через php на эту

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_shop' );
function cart_empty_redirect_to_shop(){
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_cart() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я поменял php код и вставил в <head> ваш js в таком виде --> <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document.body).on('wc_cart_emptied', function(){
     
    window.location.href = "https://domain.ru/shop/";
});

</script>  но когда удаляешь товар - перенаправления нет. Для этого нужно чтобы сначала страница перезагрузилась видимо. Если просто заходишь на пустую страницу корзины, то перенаправление включается.

Comment: похоже что вы вставили скрипт до подключения библиотеки jquery.

Comment: Нет, там ещё один jquery скрипт есть - он работает, я пробовал в футер вставлять - бесполезно.

Comment: Пробовал доллар в скобки вставить function($) - не работает

Comment: у вас есть ошиби в консоли?

Comment: Я решил проблему по своему, не знаю хорошо это или нет, я задал интервал в 5 секунд запуска вашего скрипта -- setInterval(function() {

          jQuery(document.body).on('wc_cart_emptied', function($){
     
    window.location.href = "https://domain.ru/shop/";
});                                    

            }, 5000);

Comment: не очень хороший вариант получился. вы пробовали поместить скрипт в document ready?

Comment: Не очень знаю js, если бы вы намекнули как это сделать

Comment: Стоит попробовать вот так и убедиться что вызов происходит после подключения библиотеки <script>jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(document.body).on('wc_cart_emptied', function(){ window.location.href = "domain.ru/shop"; });
});</script>

Comment: Да, так работает, можете это вставить в ответ я отмечу ) только я там доллар вставил сюда jQuery(function($)

Comment: исправил ответ.